# How to disable the loading symbol when clicking on an HTML file input

Tags: html, css

When clicking on an HTML file input `<input type="file">`, on Windows PCs, the file explorer opens up. This process takes 1 or 2 seconds and while waiting, next to the cursor appears a blue circular loading symbol. I was wondering how to disable showing this symbol.

Comment: I very much doubt you can control this, and even if you could, you probably shouldn't.

Comment: Perhaps you could describe why you need to do this - it removes a potentially valuable piece of information from the user.

Comment: I just don't like the looks of this loader. Plus, it usually vanishes very quickly. If it's not possible to disable this feature or at least style it, I could live with it as well.